# What is told about the Mahāmrityuñjaya mantra in the Purānas?

Tags: shiva, puranas, mantras, worship, reference-request

Which Purānas mention the Mahāmṛtyuñjaya Mantra? And what is told about it?

Answer (score 2):

The Puranas that mention the mantra explain that it's a very powerful one.

[Skanda Purana 1.95](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626883.html) says:

> 4. After installing the great Liṅga, he became engaged in its worship always and performed the Japa of the great Mantra well-known as Mṛtyuñjaya.
> 5. O goddess, he muttered the Mantra millions and crores of times. Thereby Lord Maheśvara became pleased. The Lord gave him chieftainship of Gaṇas and salvation called Sāmipya (nearness to the Lord).

[Shiva Purana 2.1.14](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225982.html) also has a few mentions, where they explain just how useful it is:

> 1. A person seeking knowledge shall worship Śiva, the benefactor of the world, ten million times. A person desiring Śiva’s vision shall worship Him five million times.
> 2. The Mṛtyuñjaya mantra shall be repeated half a million times when Śiva shall be visible to the devotee and fulfil his desires.
> 3. If a person repeats the mantra a hundred thousand times and begins a second instalment he will be lifted to a higher caste. When he completes the third hundred thousand times all his worldly desires will be fulfilled. In the fourth Lakṣa he will be able to see the lord.
> 4. When the fifty Lakṣa is completed, the lord will confer on him all benefits. When the same mantra is repeated a million times, the merit is tremendous.

And...

> 68-70. Dhārā worship is very efficacious in delirium due to fever. At that time Śatarudriya mantra, Rudraikādaśa mantra, Rudrajāpya mantra, Puruṣa Sūkta,Ṣaḍaṅga mantra, **Mahāmṛtyuñjaya mantra**, Gāyatrī, names ending with Namaḥ and beginning with Praṇava or Āgama mantra shall be repeated.
>
> 71. The Dhārā worship is very excellent in regard to **flourishing series of pleasures.** Different types of auspicious materials of worship shall be added to the water.
> 72. If Dhārā worship is performed with ghee continuously while a thousand mantras are repeated, **the family will undoubtedly flourish.**

Actually, though, the mantra is more of a Vedic one. It appears in the Rigveda (7.59.12), and twice in the Yajur Veda.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Does any puran states that this mantra is used for conquering death?

Comment: @Rudra - AFAIK, none of them do.

Comment: Cool, thanks for replying. And is mrit sanjeevani mantra too is some powerful beeja mantras + mrityunjaya??

Comment: @Rudra - can you clarify your question? (sorry)